# Оптимизировать код c#

Tags: c#, файлы, aes

Добрый день, нужна ваша помощь в оптимизации кода.
Задача : зашифровать часть байтов в файле алгоритмом aes c#
Как я сделал:

```
public static byte[] AES_(int len, byte[] passwordBytes, byte[] saltBytes, FileStream fSin)
        {

            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
            byte[] encryptedBytesAndIV = null;

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 100);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = generateIV();

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                        int read,read2=0;


                        while (read2 < len)
                        {
                            read = fSin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            read2 += read;
                        }
                        cs.Close();


                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    encryptedBytesAndIV = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length + AES.IV.Length];
                    AES.IV.CopyTo(encryptedBytesAndIV, 0);
                    encryptedBytes.CopyTo(encryptedBytesAndIV, IV_LENGTH);
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytesAndIV;
        }
        private static byte[] generateIV()
        {
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] nonce = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
                rng.GetBytes(nonce);
                return nonce;
            }
        }
```

и вызываю

```
 FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
len = Convert.ToInt32(fsIn.Length) / 3;
             var resultb = AES_(len, passwordBytes, saltBytes, fsIn);


                fsIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fsIn.Write(resultb, 0, resultb.Length);

                fsIn.Seek(fsIn.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fsIn.Write(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.Length);
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fsIn))
            {
                writer.Seek(Convert.ToInt32(fsIn.Length), SeekOrigin.Begin);
                writer.Write(resultb.Length);

            }
```

Проблема : при большем файле тратится очень много памяти в пк и он зависает. Как мог я оптимизировал. Насколько я понял, проблема в `MemoryStream`, ибо именно туда записываются байты и собственно на нее тратится память. Можно ли как-то сразу в файл записывать ? Разумеется, что можно вместо `MemoryStream` поставить тот же `FileStream`, но тогда придется дозаписывать оставшиеся байты, ибо в тот же `filestream` не получится записать и придется создавать новый, а это трата времени и опять же памяти. Вообщем, можете что-то подсказать ?

Comment: `FileStream` в `using` оберните.

Comment: @Николай я потом делаю `.Close` . Это единственное замечание ?

Comment: @ Lolidze я не спец в оптимизации, просто `FileStream` сразу в глаза бросился. А Вы пробовали пошагово идти и в этот момент следить за памятью? Т.к. много операций с массивами проходит, может в них где проблема.

Comment: @Николай память тратится на переменную MemoryStream, ибо туда записываются зашифрованные байты. Я немного переделал код, теперь не посылаю все байты, которые надо зашифровать, а по кускам. Раньше посылал все байты, а потом разделял буффером. Память тратится меньше, но на сколько верно написал это вопрос [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/Z4BF4eYb)